# Word 2019 Macro to convert List Bullets to simple Text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a way to convert the List Bullets in Word document to simple text.

The document has these kind of bullets:

```
•→Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
   •→Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
      •→Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
        •→Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
          •→Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
            •→Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I need them to look like this:

```
•Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
   A1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
      B1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
         C1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
            D1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
              E1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Not all of the lists go to this depth (5 levels under initial bullet), so there needs to be a way to detect the end of the list and start on the next one.

Have tried mostly manual manipulation, to no avail, like copying the Word content to various other programs in an effort to get the list text with the leading bullets and text without the Word formatting, but to no avail.

Have done rudimentary Word macros in the past, but this is somewhat complex for my limited experience. Also, have limited experience with VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The code has been tested on Microsoft 365. I hope there are no compatibility issues with Word 2019.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.listformat.convertnumberstotext?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm163578042)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [ListFormat.RemoveNumbers method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.listformat.removenumbers?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm163578041)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.InsertBefore method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertbefore?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm157155430)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub ConvertBulletsToText()
    Dim oPara As Paragraph, indentStr As String
    Dim indentLevel As Long, i As Long, aIndex() As Long
    Const INDENT_BLOCK = "   " ' indent spaces for each level, modify as needed
    Const MAX_LEVEL = 6
    ' Loop through each paragraph
    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        ' Check if the paragraph has a bullet
        If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType <> wdListNoNumbering Then
            ' Get the indentation level
           indentLevel = oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
            ' Remove the bullet from the paragraph
            If indentLevel = 1 Then
                oPara.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
                oPara.Range.Characters(2).Delete ' remove Tab after bullet
                ReDim aIndex(2 To MAX_LEVEL) ' Reset array
            Else
                If indentLevel <= MAX_LEVEL Then
                    indentStr = ""
                    For i = 2 To indentLevel
                        indentStr = indentStr & INDENT_BLOCK
                    Next
                    aIndex(indentLevel) = aIndex(indentLevel) + 1
                    indentStr = indentStr & Chr(63 + indentLevel) & aIndex(indentLevel)
                    oPara.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
                    oPara.Range.InsertBefore indentStr
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oPara
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update:

> Question: the number after the A, B, C, etc. should not be incremented. All A's should be A1's, all B's B1's etc.

```vb
Sub ConvertBulletsToText()
    Dim oPara As Paragraph, indentStr As String
    Dim indentLevel As Long, i As Long
    Const INDENT_BLOCK = "   " ' indent spaces for each level, modify as needed
    Const MAX_LEVEL = 6
    ' Loop through each paragraph
    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        ' Check if the paragraph has a bullet
        If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType <> wdListNoNumbering Then
            ' Get the indentation level
           indentLevel = oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
            ' Remove the bullet from the paragraph
            If indentLevel = 1 Then
                oPara.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
                oPara.Range.Characters(2).Delete ' remove Tab after bullet
            Else
                If indentLevel <= MAX_LEVEL Then
                    indentStr = ""
                    For i = 2 To indentLevel
                        indentStr = indentStr & INDENT_BLOCK
                    Next
                    indentStr = indentStr & Chr(63 + indentLevel) & "1"
                    oPara.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
                    oPara.Range.InsertBefore indentStr
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oPara
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! Only one tweak - the number after the A, B, C, etc. should not be incremented. All A's should be A1's, all B's B1's etc.

Comment: My bad - not being more specific about the A's and B's. This is superb!